# How to validate all inputs which exists on page?

Tags: javascript

[All inputs from page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIOiu.png)

I have this html page which is dynamical created, which contains some divs. Every div-question(0,1,2, etc) contain an input based on which answer type the user chose. I want to validate every single inputs from page and:

If value of one input type number,text,date is != "" alert("something")
else send the value in an array;
If  checkbox/radio is not checked alert("something");

I tried something like this:

```
        let nrDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("div-question");
        let existInput = nrDiv[0].querySelector("input[type='text']");
        let numberInput = nrDiv[0].querySelector("input[type='number']");
        if (document.body.contains(existInput)) {
            for (let i=0; i < nrDiv.length ;i++) {
                let container = document.getElementsByClassName("div-questions" + i + "");
                let userInputAnswer = container[0].querySelector("input[type='text']");
                if (userInputAnswer.value == "") {
                    alert("Adaugati un raspuns!")
                    return;
                } 
                 if (userInputAnswer.value != ""){
                    let answer = {
                        question: questions[i].textQuestion,
                        answer: userInputAnswer.value
                    }
                    answers.push(answer);
                }
            }
        }
```

It's working but if I come with another for loop, for input type="number" is not working anymore. I'm getting value null. So if I come with this:

```
       if (document.body.contains(numberInput)) {
            for (let i=0; i < nrDiv.length ;i++) {
                let container = document.getElementsByClassName("div-questions" + i + "");
                let userInputAnswer = container.querySelector("input[type='number']");
                if (userInputAnswer.value == "") {
                    alert("Adaugati un raspuns!")
                    return;
                } 
                 if (userInputAnswer.value != ""){
                    let answer = {
                        question: questions[i].textQuestion,
                        answer: userInputAnswer.value
                    }
                    answers.push(answer);
                }
            }
        }
```

And for the checkbox and radio inputs I don't have any idea. I want something like this:

If all inputs are not empty and minimum one checkbox/radio is checked, send the answer and question in an array else alert("error");

Comment: Did you try adding the `required` attribute?

Comment: It's working now, but I need to take all the value of inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this is simple once you add the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute and/or a [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern).

This is a simple POC:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" required>
  <input type="number" required>
  <input type="checkbox" required>
  <input type="radio" required>
  <input type="date" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Notice that when you click the `submit` button, it does the verification you want, in this case `!= ""`.

Comment: Thank you, now I need to take all the inputs value.